# Determine if $f(x)$ is integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

verify if $f$ is integrable, where
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } x \not\in \mathbb{Q}\\
1/q &\text{if x = $p/q$, where $p,q > 0$ are relatively prime integers} 
\end{cases}
$$
over the interval [0,1].

I am trying to prove that the set of discontinuity points is the set of rationals, which has zero measure and therefore the function would be integrable. But I don't know how to prove this continuity.

Edit: As in the comment below, it seems that this function is discontinued on all points, and the problem now comes down to proving this statement

Comment: Isn’t this function discontinuous everywhre?

Comment: Or do you mean $0$ ?

Comment: Hmm, really. And in this case my function would be non-integrable. Do you have any idea how I could prove the discontinuity?

Comment: Try to use the sequential definition of a limit .by this method you will also see that if the function was $0$ at the irrationals then it would be continuous at irrationals and hence integrable .

Comment: I'll try, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's not $f(x) = 0$ for $x \notin \mathbb Q$? That's the canonical definition of the Thomae Function, which has considerably different (and much more interesting) properties.

Comment: It's Lebesgue-integrable, but not Riemann-integrable. Which one did you mean? (But if you define $f(x)=0$ for irrational $x$, it is Riemann-integrable too.)

Comment: @user149513: This Wikipedia link on the [Thomae function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 1):

If we take $\bar x\in[0,1]\cap(\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q)$ and fix $\varepsilon>0$, then it will always exist a nbh $\mathcal U(\bar x)$ in which $f(x)<\varepsilon$. In other words $\underset{[0,1]\ni x\to\bar x}{\lim}f(x)=0$.
Therefore $f$ is continuos $\textbf{almost eveywhere}$ since it is continuous in $[0,1]\cap(\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q)$ (where $\mathbb Q\cong\mathbb N\times\mathbb Z$, so it is countable and for this reason $|\mathbb Q|=0$).